# How to change IntelliJ's reformat code style for enums?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

Is it possible to change the reformat behavior in Intellij 2016.3.4 from:

```
private enum Suit {CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS}
```

to:

```
private enum Suit { CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS }
```

(as recommended in [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.1-enum-classes))? None of the Java code style settings for spaces seem to have any effect.

Another issue: reformat will also force any enums that have Javadoc to multiple lines.  E.g., from:

```
/** Javadoc. */
private enum Suit {CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS}
```

to:

```
/** Javadoc. */
private enum Suit {
    CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS
}
```

Is it possible to disable this behvior?

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, please vote:

- [IDEA-162495](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162495) Add Java Code Style setting for Spaces -> Within -> Enum braces